# what is the R code for splitting a column

Tags: r

This is the table I have

| Product | Days | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Google | MTWTHFSASU | 28000 |
| Apple | THFSASU | 10000 |

Days denote Monday to Sunday and I need to create an output like this using R.

| Product | Days | Sales | No of Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | M | 4000 | 7 |
| Google | T | 4000 | 7 |
| Google | W | 4000 | 7 |
| Google | TH | 4000 | 7 |
| Google | F | 4000 | 7 |
| Google | SA | 4000 | 7 |
| Google | SU | 4000 | 7 |
| Apple | TH | 2500 | 4 |
| Apple | F | 2500 | 4 |
| Apple | SA | 2500 | 4 |
| Apple | SU | 2500 | 4 |

Can you someone help me on how to split the days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the characters to extract are overlapping, it may be better to use `str_extract_all` to extract each of them with an OR (`|`) to a `list` column, get the `lengths` of the `list` to create 'No_of_Days', divide the 'Sales' by the 'No_of_Days' and `unnest` the list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Days = str_extract_all(Days, "M|T|W|TH|F|SA|SU"),
         No_of_Days = lengths(Days),
         Sales = Sales/No_of_Days) %>%
  unnest(c(Days))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 4
#   Product Days  Sales No_of_Days
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>      <int>
# 1 Google  M      4000          7
# 2 Google  T      4000          7
# 3 Google  W      4000          7
# 4 Google  T      4000          7
# 5 Google  F      4000          7
# 6 Google  SA     4000          7
# 7 Google  SU     4000          7
# 8 Apple   T      2500          4
# 9 Apple   F      2500          4
#10 Apple   SA     2500          4
#11 Apple   SU     2500          4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Product = c("Google", "Apple"), Days = c("MTWTHFSASU", 
"THFSASU"), Sales = c(28000L, 10000L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. it works perfectly

Comment: I would like to add an extra layer here. I want to include a date into the final file where I have start date like "01/01/2021". So for values with "M" it should have a date as "01/01/2021".

Comment: @BadriNarayanan Can you post as a new question. thanks

Comment: one more question is if I want to add an additional column called date. where I want to input the start file from a txt file. Lets consider that the start date I have chosen is "01/01/2021". I want the Monday to have "01/01/2021" and the Sunday to have "01/07/2021". this is how I want the final output to be.

Comment: @BadriNarayanan Please post as a new question so that it is easier to understand

Comment: | Product  | Days     |SALES      |NO_OF_DAYS     |DATE           |
| --------     | -------------- |-------------- |-------------- |-------------- |             
| Google   | M      |4000          |7              |01/01/2021     |
| Google   | W      |4000          |7              |01/03/2021     |
| Google   | SA      |4000          |7              |01/06/2021     |
| Google   | SU      |4000          |7              |01/07/2021     |
| Apple      | T      |2500          |4              |01/02/2021     |
| Apple     | F      |2500          |4              |01/05/2021     |

Comment: @BadriNarayanan can you post as a new question?